# According to Catholic Tradition: Was Jesus a Genius?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, christology

- According to Catholic Tradition: Was Jesus a Genius?

  - Did He possess at least a 21st century education of the world and of science?
  - For instance, if He had the tools and He wanted to, could He perform brain surgery?

Comment: comments aren't required. You don't define what is the measure of genius, nor a denomination scope (while not always necessary, this can change answer), 21st century and brain surgery aren't mentioned in the bible so opinion. You also don't really provide any research that you've done

Comment: @depperm Research? I didn't know the bar was that high on Christianity.SE.

Comment: @depperm Why not just use the standard definition? Such as "an exceptional natural capacity of intellect, especially as shown in creative and original work in science, art, music, etc."

Comment: @JimG. surely a member with 7 gold badges and two thousand rep should be aware of how the system works here?

Answer (score 3):

Trinitarians will say Jesus was 'fully human' - as such, the question is applicable and can be rephrased as 'in his human nature' or some such thing.

What Jesus says and does conveys significant intelligence. He was clearly very familiar with the Jewish scriptures, and innovated theologically (some examples are given [here](https://www.adventistworld.org/the-innovative-jesus/)). He was clearly precocious in this area, as in [Luke 2:46-47](https://biblehub.com/bsb/luke/2.htm).

> "46 Finally, after three days they found Him in the temple courts,
> sitting among the teachers, listening to them and asking them
> questions. 47 And all who heard Him were astounded at His
> understanding and His answers."

He probably could [read and write](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14680/51878), which would be an unusual accomplishment for his time given his background as a carpenter's son. He engaged in high-level debate or discussion with Jewish scribes (an example, see [Mark 12](https://biblehub.com/bsb/mark/12.htm)) - the intelligentsia of the time - apparently leaving them incapable of a good response at times.

Given this, I think it's reasonable to conclude Jesus was highly intelligent.

Comment: *Luke 2:40* "And the child grew, and waxed strong, full of wisdom; and the grace of God was in him."

Comment: @SolaGratia Right. Also Luke 2:52 "And Jesus grew in wisdom and stature, and in favor with God and man."

Comment: Does your username imply you don't believe in God the Son, through whom God made everything, who was with God in the beginning, and was God? Or are you only emphasizing the monarchy of the Father?

Comment: @SolaGratia I'm just quoting St. Paul, but I believe St. Paul was a unitarian Christian and am one myself - after realizing the scriptural arguments for trinitarianism weren't as strong as I had been led to believe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Being God, Christ had divine knowledge, knowing Himself perfectly. Having a human nature, he also had [infused](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP009.html#TPQ9A3THEP1) and [acquired knowledge](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP009.html#TPQ9A4THEP1).

Explaining "Whether Christ had any knowledge besides the Divine?" ([*Summa Theologica* III q. 9 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP009.html#TPQ9A1THEP1)), St. Thomas Aquinas writes (co.):

> the Son of God assumed an entire human nature, i.e. not only a body, but also a soul, and not only a sensitive, but also a **rational soul**. And therefore it behooved Him to have created knowledge, for three reasons.
>
> 1. on account of the soul's perfection. […]
> 2. because, […] Christ would have had an intellective soul to no purpose if He had not understood by it; and this pertains to created knowledge.
> 3. because some created knowledge pertains to the nature of the human soul, viz. that whereby we naturally know first principles; since we are here taking knowledge for any cognition of the human intellect. Now nothing natural was wanting to Christ, since He took the whole human nature, as stated above ([q. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP005.html#TPQ5OUTP1)). And hence the Sixth Council [*[Third Council of Constantinople](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04310a.htm), Act. 4] condemned the opinion of those who denied that in Christ there are two knowledges or wisdoms.

Now, did "the soul of Christ" "know all things in the Word" ([*Summa Theologica* III q. 10 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP010.html#TPQ10A2THEP1))? St. Thomas answers (co.):

> When it is inquired whether Christ knows all things in the Word, "all things" may be taken in two ways:
>
> 1. properly, to stand for all that in any way **whatsoever is, will be, or was done, said, or thought, by whomsoever and at any time**. And in this way it must be said that **the soul of Christ knows** all things in the Word. For every created intellect knows in the Word, not all simply, but so many more things the more perfectly it sees the Word. […]
> 2. "all things" may be taken widely, as extending not merely to such things as are in act at some time, but even to such **things as are in potentiality**, and never have been nor ever will be reduced to actuality.
>
>    - Now some of these are in the Divine power alone, and **not all of these does the soul of Christ know in the Word**. For this would be to comprehend all that God could do, which would be to comprehend the Divine power, and, consequently, the Divine Essence. For every power is known from the knowledge of all it can do.
>    - Some, however, are not only in the power of God, but also **in the power of the creature; and all of these the soul of Christ knows in the Word**; for it comprehends in the Word the essence of every creature, and, consequently, its power and virtue, and all things that are in the power of the creature.

Thus, Christ's human soul knows all what creatures can do,* but it does not understand all what God can possibly (but has not and will not) do.

<sup>*This includes what human creatures have done creating "21st century education of the world and of science" and "brain surgery".</sup>

Christ even had wonder, in his empiric (experiential) knowledge, "in order to teach us to wonder at what He Himself wondered at." ([*Summa Theologica* III q. 15 a. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP015.html#TPQ15A8THEP1) co.).

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: this answer assumes a Trinitarian perspective.)

What do you mean by "genius"?

Jesus ***is God***. God "hid" certain knowledge from "himself" (i.e. His incarnation as Christ) during said incarnation, but aside from those exceptions, Jesus *was (still) omniscient*. There are a few examples where He knew of events occurring far away, and at least one where he was aware of a person's thoughts.

Jesus is *the Author of Life* (see Genesis 1-2, John 1). Asking if the entity that *made humans* (and everything else in all of Creation) has "at least a 21st century education of the world and of science", or enough knowledge to perform brain surgery, is rather silly.

Anyway, at least when it comes to brain surgery, I doubt He would bother; he performed *many* healing miracles and even three resurrections (counting Himself). I can't imagine why, if He desired to heal someone, He wouldn't just *do* so. Similarly, He is recorded as creating bread, fish and wine miraculously. It stands to reason that He can create any artifact He wishes, whether by natural means (i.e. using tools) or supernatural.

That all said... consider Luke 2:41-52:

> <sup>48</sup> [Jesus' parents] found [twelve-year-old Jesus] in the temple, sitting among the teachers, listening to them and asking them questions. <sup>47</sup> And all who heard him were amazed at his understanding and his answers.

At minimum, the Bible teaches that Jesus possessed a noteworthy degree of wisdom, which might match one possible definition of "genius".

Comment: "God "hid" certain knowledge from "himself" (i.e. His incarnation as Christ) during said incarnation, but aside from those exceptions, Jesus was (still) omniscient." Can you name anything outside of spiritual matters Jesus said that wasn't something a relatively well-educated, smart person of his time and place wouldn't know?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, nothing comes to mind, but nor would I expect for such things to be recorded. What *is* recorded is that Jesus had tremendous knowledge of the Scripture, even from a very young age (Luke 2:41-52). That said, I think your distinction cannot be justified. Spiritual revelation *transcends* mere knowledge / intelligence / education. It is not justifiable to argue that Christ knows *heavenly* things but does *not* know earthly things.

Comment: Thanks for this response - yes, I think his familiarity with and ability to absorb, parse, handle, and synthesize scriptures indicates something important here.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I think the mainstream position is that Jesus stick to his mission by **not** accessing His divine nature that is outside the scope of his mission.  He "blinded himself" to be a regular 1st century Nazareth Jew, except a few occasions like miracles, prophecies, discernment, etc.  A CIA agent in Russia would be a good analogy: try to pass by like a regular Russian.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple A *few* occasions?! ;)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Here you go, thousands of Russians following me everywhere, I'm going to hand out thousands of U.S.-stamped rations that I've called in from my CIA helicopter. Now whoop! I have to disappear and pretend I'm a normal Russian again. ;)

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Hehehe... ok, ok not a good analogy, just want illustrate how he would appear to his family and friends.  But intentionally, he did want to join into the human suffering without cheating though.  Otherwise, it's docetism.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple But yes, I agree with your point. Or perhaps you could say he intentionally 'humbled' himself, as St. Paul puts it, which included 'blinding' himself in terms of his knowledge.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Sure, that's the original term in [Phil 2:6-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+2%3A1-11&version=ESV).  I just want to be more concrete in showing what "humbling" involves.  I stole the idea from [Eleonore Stump](https://www.closertotruth.com/interviews/58405) who likens Jesus taking on human nature by putting dark contact lenses who can still take them out when he needs to.

Answer (score -1):

> My goal is that they may be encouraged in heart and united in love, so
> that they may have the full riches of complete understanding, in order
> that they may know the mystery of God, namely, Christ, in whom are
> hidden **all the treasures of wisdom and knowledge**. (Colossians 2:2-3)

If Christ possesses all wisdom and knowledge, I guess that includes brain surgery.

In the Socratic method, the interchange between teacher and student probes reality and reveals new truths. That interaction is essential. The student's act of asking questions propels the teacher to new understanding, for himself and for his pupils.

Jesus did not need the Socratic method.

> 29 Then Jesus’ disciples said, “Now you are speaking clearly and
> without figures of speech. 30 Now we can see that you know all things
> and that you do not even need to have anyone ask you questions. This
> makes us believe that you came from God.” (John 16:29-30)

The above is an affirmation that Jesus had attained perfect knowledge by the time of the Last Supper.

Comment: +1 for that reference. It doesn't seem this straightforward, though. Luke 2:40 "and the child grew and was strengthened in spirit, being filled with wisdom, and the grace of God was upon him." (Young's Literal)

Comment: Similarly, Luke 2:52 "And Jesus grew in wisdom and stature, and in favor with God and man."

Comment: At his baptism, the Holy Spirit descended upon him, which surely dealt with any remaining "growing in stature" that was required.

Comment: That sounds right to me (but still he struggled, see the Garden of Gethsemane). But that doesn't address the problem - Paul says in Christ are 'all treasures of wisdom and knowledge'. Does this mean Jesus, in his human nature for 33 years while walking on the earth, was omniscient or even a genius, say? I don't think it speaks directly to it.

Comment: I would divide Jesus' submission into three steps: mind, heart and body. The intellectual assent was at the temptation in the desert. The emotional assent was at Gethsemane. The physical assent was permitting himself to be arrested and all that followed. Since you ask about knowledge, the final growth in heart and obedient action might not be required for completion of Jesus' knowledge.