# Is violence against LGBT people warranted by scripture?

Tags: violence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Biblical basis for hating homosexuals?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/is-there-any-biblical-basis-for-hating-homosexuals)

This week marks the 13th anniversary of Matthew Shepherd's torture and murder, a crime which appears to be motivated by disgust for who he was as a homosexual.

Many Christians read the Bible to prohibit homosexual acts. Does the scripture advocate or justify violence against people who commit sexual sins?

Comment: Admittedly, there's a bit of difference between violence and hating.  However, I think that "hate" would definitely cover violence.  Therefore, I'm agreeing that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Whoops--didn't even realize there was another question on this topic. The issue came up in relation to discussions around another question, and I found it relevant to make clear what scripture says on the subject of violence against homosexuals.

Answer (score 8):

No, as little as it advocates violence against any other sinner. The story in John 8 holds for homosexuals as well: He who is without sin throw the first stone. And when nobody did: Go therefore and don't sin no more.

Comment: I agree, but I would use other passages to make the argument [given what we know about John 8](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-is-the-practical-application-of-the-story-of-the-woman-caught-in-adultery/2992#2992).

Answer (score 2):

Jesus advocates using means other than violence ([Mt. 5:38-48](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205:38-48&version=ESV), [Mt. 26:51-52](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2026:51-52&version=ESV)).

According to Paul, [we shouldn't even be cruel nor hateful](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3281/60) towards others:

> [**Romans 12:16-21 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%2012:16-21&version=ESV)
>    <sup>16</sup>  Live in harmony with one another. Do not be haughty, but associate with the lowly. Never be wise in your own sight. <sup>17</sup>  Repay no one evil for evil, but give thought to do what is honorable in the sight of all. <sup>18</sup> **If possible, so far as it depends on you, live peaceably with all.** <sup>19</sup> Beloved, never avenge yourselves, but leave it to the wrath of God, for it is written, "Vengeance is mine, I will repay, says the Lord." <sup>20</sup> To the contrary, "if your enemy is hungry, feed him; if he is thirsty, give him something to drink; for by so doing you will heap burning coals on his head." <sup>21</sup> Do not be overcome by evil, but **overcome evil with good**.

If we have the choice, we should live in peace with all and be good to everyone. Even if they're evil. Even if they're our enemy. Even if they're sinners.

**No, the Bible doesn't advocate violence towards sinners** ([which we all are](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2646/60)).

Answer (score 0):

Violence is certainly not permissible against any immoral acts.  However, in the Law of Moses that detailed the covenant relationship between God and Israel, God did command certain punishments for various crimes, including robbery, adultery, etc.  This is a function of community governance, though, and not personal violence.  Furthermore, it only applies within the context of God's covenant relationship with Israel.  It is how Israel was supposed to govern themselves as a nation--not how individuals should respond to others.  The punishments did include capital punishment.

The Sermon on the Mount, by contrast, specifies behavior for individual people and not the government.

So, we do unto others how we want them to do to us, but we don't make that the rule of government.  This would result in absolute lawlessness.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your opening statement?  And maybe specific references to your other points (violence as punishment by government, etc)

Comment: The Sermon on the Mount is directed at individuals, which makes no allowance for that.  The Levitical Law provides specific penalties for certain offenses.

Comment: Good... can you update the answer with references to those?